# Set user-specific password hashing rounds in PAM

Tags: password, pam

In `/etc/pam.d/common-password` we have a line such as:

```
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so sha512 rounds=200000
```

Meaning, whenever anyone sets their password, hash it with 200,000
rounds of SHA-512. This inherently slow hashing protects against
dictionary and brute-force attacks by limiting the speed at which
passwords can be tested.

For some accounts we might want to protect the password better, at the
expense of slower hashing. Say, 500,000 rounds for an admin account, and
800,000 for `root`. But I have not been able to find any way to specify
such per-user or per-group policies in PAM. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify per-user or per-group policies through the [`pam_succeed_if`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_succeed_if.html) module. Use the [“goto” action](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html) (i.e. an integer instead of `ok`, `ignore`, etc.) to skip over a `password` setting for some users.

```
password [success=1] pam_succeed_if user ne 0
# Setting for root
password [success=1] pam_unix.so sha512 rounds=800000
# Setting for non-root
password [success=ok] pam_unix.so sha512 rounds=200000
```

(Warning: untested and I'm not fluent in PAM.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Looks like I'll have to do some reading and experiments before I can vote on it.